# General formula for entries of matrix product

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes

Suppose I have a sequence of $3\times 3$ column stochastic matrices $A_1,\dots,A_n$ (whose entries may depend on some parameter). Is there any hope in computing the matrix
$$\prod_{k=1}^nA_k$$
so that the entries of the resulting matrix can be analytically computed as $n\to\infty$. I ask this because in the $2\times 2$ case I have been able to obtain a formula for this product where the entries are given by some infinite series as $n\to\infty$ and was interested in whether this could be generalised to larger matrices.

Comment: $(AB)_{ij} = \sum\limits_k a_{ik} b_{kj}$; $(ABC)_{ij} = (AB \cdot C)_{ij} = \sum\limits_k (AB)_{ik} c_{kj} = \sum\limits_{k,m} a_{im} b_{mk} c_{kj}$, $\ldots$, $(A_1 \ldots A_n)_{ij} = \sum\limits_{k_1,\ldots, k_{n-1}} (A_1)_{ik_1} (A_2)_{k_1 k_2} \cdots (A_n)_{k_{n-1} j}$. Or did I get you wrong?